# Await end of Parallel.Invoke() in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I have the following code :

```
Parallel.Invoke(
                () => this.GetUsers(), 
                () => this.GetFrequentVisitors(),
                () => this.GetTenantSettings(),
                () => this.GetTranslations()
            );
```

All of these are `Async Task` methods, all of them together take about 30 sec, and in parallel should take about 7.

Right now, if I log time just before and after the `Parallel.Invoke`, I have less than a second.

My questions are : Why ? And how do I `await` the `.Invoke()` so I know when the last of the calls is finished?

Right now I can only achieve what appears to be either everything instantly, which seems wrong, or everything in sequence, which is unbearable for the user.

I have also tried this :

```
    Task users = this.GetUsers();
    Task visitors = this.GetFrequentVisitors();
    Task settings = this.GetTenantSettings();
    Task translations = this.GetTranslations();


    Task.WaitAll(users, visitors, settings, translations);
```

Which appears to just hang there forever and blocking my app.

Note : this is in an `async Task` method which I am awaiting, but there is no await inside (what I showed is the complete method). If I change it I get no different result.

Can anyone help me out a bit? With a little explanation ? I'm struggling with async / threading right now.

Reading this  [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963549.aspx) helped a little, but they don't seem to need to `await` the `.Invoke()` which surprises me.

Comment: If all methods you've mentioned are async ones, then why don't just do something like `await GetUsers(); await GetFrequentVisitors();` and so on?

Comment: `Parellel.Invoke` blocks. You don't neet (can't) to await it. In fact, it uses the current thread to execute one of the methods. What do the methods do? Why do you think something is wrong? If the methods are actually asynchronous, you need `Task.WaitAll` or `Task.WhenAll`, not Parallel.Invoke

Comment: @AndyKorneyev that would execute the methods sequentially, not in parallel

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I don't want to await them all in line because they take a really long time to execute. I would like to have them executed all as once on different threads. Each takes about 5 to 7 seconds to execute.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos doesn't Task.WaitAll executes sequentially? Why is my code hanging when I execute the block I've showed in the question?

Comment: If the methods are asynchronous, why don't you use `await Task.WhenAll(...)` ? Parallel.Invoke *runs* its synchronous arguments in parallel

Comment: @Zil no it doesn't. It *awaits* for all tasks to complete by blocking. To await asynchronously, use `await Task.WhenAll`

Comment: Well I want to use the F word. Thanks guys, this is exactly the behaviour I'm expecting now. It's all fine with `.WhenAll()´.
Thank you everyone :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With your `WaitAll` variant "hanging forever", it suggests that you're on, say, the UI thread, and one or more of those methods wants to also get onto the UI thread.

Change this current method to be `async` so that you can instead `await`:

```
Task users = this.GetUsers();
Task visitors = this.GetFrequentVisitors();
Task settings = this.GetTenantSettings();
Task translations = this.GetTranslations();

await Task.WhenAll(users, visitors, settings, translations);
```

And, importantly, this will now free up the UI thread (or other important synchronization context) so that these other async methods can make progress.

Comment: Let me try this, WhenAll looks promising, didn't know it existed :l

Comment: Well, this works just fine. Thanks everyone for helping, that's why I like this community.
Looking at your comments and the documentation, it's now all clear and actually pretty obvious.

Comment: Parallel.Invoke() Aggregate exception and you can catch aggregated exception through catch(AggregateException) can we do the same with the above said